# How to run react native 0.63 applications in XCode 13?

Tags: ios, reactjs, xcode, react-native

I'm mantaining a React Native app written with v0.63.2 of the framework.

In order to develop for iOS 15 I have upgraded XCode to v13 and I saw that the `xcrun` was deleted (it was already deprecated in XCode 12).
That command was needed by react-native to start by app for local development. As far as I know, to work with iOS 15 I'll have to upgrade to react-native 0.66 and I can't do that right now.
Here I have two questions:

1. Is there a way to develop with XCode 13 using a version of react-native minor than 0.66 (please note that upgrading to 0.64 or 0.65 is still NOT an option for me)?
2. Is there a fix / equivalent about the `xcrun` command ?

Comment: I believe that if you build for iOS (with react-native), you can find a xcode project file that you can open with xcode. After that, if you have everything else setup. You should just need to hit "run".

Comment: Thanks @ANicholasson. The problem is that if I run the app with XCode I lose all the React Native debug tools and I don't want this. Any further suggestion?

Comment: What means by losing all the React Native debug tools? I always run my app in Xcode and working all the time.

Answer (score 1):

There was an issue on the build for Xcode 13 here https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31733

Fix:
Replace this line (in the `project.pbxproj`):

```
"\"$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/usr/lib/swift-5.0/$(PLATFORM_NAME)\"",
```

by this one:

```
"\"$(SDKROOT)/usr/lib/swift\"",
```